# Python setup.py build doesn't use the latest setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing setup.py to use C library from python.

The problem is after updating setup.py and call the following commands I don't see any changes.

```
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

Is there such a command as clean build in this setup.py ?
It seems that it's still using the previous build.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command before doing another build

```
python setup.py clean --all
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work. Even if I update C code it still uses the old one.

Comment: Dang. Ok. The problem was because I started using "python3" instead of "python". Thanks for your help :)